# How can we set the Wrap-point for the WrapPanel?

Tags: wpf, word-wrap, wrappanel, uniformgrid

I have an ItemsControl and I want the data to be entered into two columns. When the User resizes to a width lesser than the second column, the items of the second column must wrap into the first column. Something like a UniformGrid but with wrapping.

I have managed to use a WrapPanel to do this. But I am forced to manipulate and hard code the ItemWidth and MaxWidth of the WrapPanel to achieve the two columns thing and the wrapping. This is not a good practice.

Is there anyway to set the Maximum no of columns or in other words allowing us to decide at what point the WrapPanel should start wrapping?

Some browsing on the internet revealed that the WrapGrid in Windows 8 Metro has this [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.wrapgrid.maximumrowsorcolumns.aspx). Does anyone have this implementation in WPF?

Comment: I think that's how a `WrapPanel` is supposed to work... draw every item until the next item doesn't fit, then wrap to a new line. You're supposed to use the `ItemWidth` and `WrapPanel.Width` (or `MaxWidth`) to tell the `WrapPanel` when to wrap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an [UniformWrapPanel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32629/A-better-panel-for-data-binding-to-a-WrapPanel-in) article on codeproject.com, which I modified to ensure the items in a wrap panel have uniform width and fit to the width of the window.  You should easily be able to modify this code to have a maximum number of columns.  Try changing the code near

```
var itemsPerRow = (int) (totalWidth/ItemWidth);
```

in order to specify the max columns.

Here's the code:

```
public enum ItemSize
{
    None,
    Uniform,
    UniformStretchToFit
}

public class UniformWrapPanel : WrapPanel
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemSizeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ItemSize", 
            typeof (ItemSize), 
            typeof (UniformWrapPanel), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                default(ItemSize),
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure,
                ItemSizeChanged));

    private static void ItemSizeChanged(
        DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var uniformWrapPanel = sender as UniformWrapPanel;
        if (uniformWrapPanel != null)
        {
            if (uniformWrapPanel.Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
            {
                uniformWrapPanel.ItemWidth = double.NaN;
            }
            else
            {
                uniformWrapPanel.ItemHeight = double.NaN;
            }
        }
    }

    public ItemSize ItemSize
    {
        get { return (ItemSize) GetValue(ItemSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemSizeProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        var mode = ItemSize;

        if (Children.Count > 0 && mode != ItemSize.None)
        {
            bool stretchToFit = mode == ItemSize.UniformStretchToFit;

            if (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
            {
                double totalWidth = availableSize.Width;

                ItemWidth = 0.0;
                foreach (UIElement el in Children)
                {
                    el.Measure(availableSize);
                    Size next = el.DesiredSize;
                    if (!(Double.IsInfinity(next.Width) || Double.IsNaN(next.Width)))
                    {
                        ItemWidth = Math.Max(next.Width, ItemWidth);
                    }
                }

                if (stretchToFit)
                {
                    if (!double.IsNaN(ItemWidth) && !double.IsInfinity(ItemWidth) && ItemWidth > 0)
                    {
                        var itemsPerRow = (int) (totalWidth/ItemWidth);
                        if (itemsPerRow > 0)
                        {
                            ItemWidth = totalWidth/itemsPerRow;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                double totalHeight = availableSize.Height;

                ItemHeight = 0.0;
                foreach (UIElement el in Children)
                {
                    el.Measure(availableSize);
                    Size next = el.DesiredSize;
                    if (!(Double.IsInfinity(next.Height) || Double.IsNaN(next.Height)))
                    {
                        ItemHeight = Math.Max(next.Height, ItemHeight);
                    }
                }

                if (stretchToFit)
                {
                    if (!double.IsNaN(ItemHeight) && !double.IsInfinity(ItemHeight) && ItemHeight > 0)
                    {
                        var itemsPerColumn = (int) (totalHeight/ItemHeight);
                        if (itemsPerColumn > 0)
                        {
                            ItemHeight = totalHeight/itemsPerColumn;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet! Thanks Phil. I managed to tailor this according to my requirement. Btw are there any performance issues in using a WrapPanel?

Comment: I couldn't say about performance.  Seems to work ok with around 30-40 items.  You'll need to try it.