# Is there a control to arrange a variable number of sub-controls?

Tags: wpf-controls

Does anyone know how to find or make a WPF container control that will display a two dimensional array of fixed-size sub-controls (the number of sub-controls varying at run time) such that the first row is filled, then the second row, and so on, until there are no more sub-controls or all the rows are filled. If the user makes the container wider then the number of columns should increase, so:
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
would become
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9

Comment: I assume you know about WrapPanel?

Comment: I do now. A very nice man called Vesuvius pointed me at a very useful demo project at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771331%28v=vs.90%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771331%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which I think will give me what I need.

Comment: Ok, well check out my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769618/how-can-we-set-the-wrap-point-for-the-wrappanel/9770590#9770590 which may help if you need a uniform wrap panel.