# How to create UniformGrid in XAML with autoscrolls after exceding rows limit by elements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uniformgrid

I would like to create `UniformGrid` which will contain `WindowsFormsHosts`(inside them are `WinForms`). 4 Hosts in every row(4 cols) and after exceding its' visible capacity new elements will be added underneath and user will be able to scroll the `UniformGrid`. I do not know even where to start beside defining UniFormGrid and its' column number.

```
 <UniformGrid x:Name="Grid"  Columns="4">

    </UniformGrid>
```

The behaviour I would like to get is just like in Windows' explorer if there are too many icons in the view you can scroll down.

**I used `UniformGrid` because I needed equivalent of `GridLayout()` in Java. I want every added element to be the same size. I add elements from .cs.**

Comment: Would a `WrapPanel` give you the behaviour you're after? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Chris No. But I think the `ScrollViewer` would. The problem is that I just start learning XAML. The behaviour I would like to get is just like in Windows' explorer if there are too many icons in the view you can scroll down.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just extend this out from the comments, depending on what size your `WinForm` controls are, and depending on what your desired resizing behaviour is, you might be able to get away with simply wrapping a `WrapPanel` in a `ScrollViewer`, e.g:

```
    <ScrollViewer>
        <WrapPanel>
            <Grid Width="100" Height="100" Background="Red"/>
            <Grid Width="100" Height="100" Background="Blue"/>
            <Grid Width="100" Height="100" Background="Yellow"/>
            <Grid Width="100" Height="100" Background="Red"/>
            <Grid Width="100" Height="100" Background="Blue"/>
            <Grid Width="100" Height="100" Background="Yellow"/>
            <Grid Width="100" Height="100" Background="Red"/>
            <Grid Width="100" Height="100" Background="Blue"/>
            <Grid Width="100" Height="100" Background="Yellow"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

[image]

For more flexibility,  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769618/how-can-we-set-the-wrap-point-for-the-wrappanel) links to a project that provides a `UniformWrapPanel`, and is worth a look.

Comment: I used `UniformGrid` because I needed equivalent of `GridLayout()` in Java. I want every added element to be the same size. I add elements from .cs.

Comment: Ah, then that link may be what you're after. You could also try setting the `Columns` property on a `UniformGrid` to your desired number of columns, and similarly wrapping it in a `ScrollViewer`.