# How can I display items in a ListView horizontally in Xamarin.forms xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm displaying a list of SQLite objects in a `ListView`, but I want them to display horizontally. So instead of this:

```
| longitem        |
| item            |
| evenlongeritem  |
| item            |
| longeritem      |
```

I want this:

```
| longitem item   |
| evenlongeritem  |
| item longeritem |
```

Importantly, the items can be of varying widths, so just breaking the list into a certain number of columns would be an improvement, but not ideal. I also don't know the number of items.

Here's the code I have currently:

```
<ListView x:Name="inactiveList" VerticalOptions="Start" ItemTapped="PutBack">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black">
                  <TextCell.ContextActions>
                         <MenuItem Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference ListPage}, Path=DeleteListItem}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="delete" />
                  </TextCell.ContextActions>
              </TextCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code Behind:

```
public ListPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ObservableCollection<ListItem> activeItems =
        new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(
            App.ListItemRepo.GetActiveListItems());
    activeList.ItemsSource = activeItems;
    ...
```

I tried just wrapping the `ViewCell` in a horizontal `StackLayout`, but I got this error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is
>   not valid.

I'm not sure that that error means, but I don't think it's possible to add a `StackLayout` inside the `DataTemplate`. I also can't make the `ListView` horizontal.

--

### UPDATE 4:

I finally could make simple labels be listed horizontally, but now I'm having trouble recreating the tap and long-press actions built into the vertical ListView. Is that possible to do?

**ListView.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Myapp">
        <!-- ... -->
        <local:WrapLayout x:Name="inactiveList" ItemsSource="{Binding .}" Spacing="5" />
```

**ListView.xaml.cs**

```
using Myapp.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using SQLite;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using DLToolkit.Forms.Controls;

namespace Myapp
{
    public partial class ListPage
    {
        ...
        public ListPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ObservableCollection<ListItem> inactiveItems =
                new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(
                    App.ListItemRepo.GetInactiveListItems());
            inactiveList.ItemsSource = inactiveItems;
            inactiveList.HeightRequest = 50 * inactiveItems.Count;


        }
        ...
    }

    public class WrapLayout : Layout<View>
    {

        public ObservableCollection<ListItem> ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<ListItem>)GetValue(ItemSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemSourceProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create
            (
                "ItemsSource",
                typeof(ObservableCollection<ListItem>),
                typeof(WrapLayout),
                propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) => ((WrapLayout)bindable).AddViews()
            );


        void AddViews()
        {
            Children.Clear();
            foreach (ListItem s in ItemsSource)
            {
                Button button = new Button();
                button.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
                button.Text = s.Name;
                button.TextColor = Color.Black;
                button.Clicked = "{Binding Source={x:Reference ListPage}, Path=PutBack}";
                Children.Add(button);
            }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty SpacingProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create
            (
                "Spacing",
                typeof(double),
                typeof(WrapLayout),
                10.0,
                propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) => ((WrapLayout)bindable).OnSizeChanged()
            );

        public double Spacing
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(SpacingProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SpacingProperty, value); }
        }

        private void OnSizeChanged()
        {
            this.ForceLayout();
        }

        protected override SizeRequest OnMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
        {
            if (WidthRequest > 0)
                widthConstraint = Math.Min(widthConstraint, WidthRequest);
            if (HeightRequest > 0)
                heightConstraint = Math.Min(heightConstraint, HeightRequest);

            double internalWidth = double.IsPositiveInfinity(widthConstraint) ? double.PositiveInfinity : Math.Max(0, widthConstraint);
            double internalHeight = double.IsPositiveInfinity(heightConstraint) ? double.PositiveInfinity : Math.Max(0, heightConstraint);

            return DoHorizontalMeasure(internalWidth, internalHeight);
        }

        private SizeRequest DoHorizontalMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
        {
            int rowCount = 1;

            double width = 0;
            double height = 0;
            double minWidth = 0;
            double minHeight = 0;
            double widthUsed = 0;

            foreach (var item in Children)
            {
                var size = item.Measure(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);

                height = Math.Max(height, size.Request.Height);

                var newWidth = width + size.Request.Width + Spacing;
                if (newWidth > widthConstraint)
                {
                    rowCount++;
                    widthUsed = Math.Max(width, widthUsed);
                    width = size.Request.Width;
                }
                else
                    width = newWidth;

                minHeight = Math.Max(minHeight, size.Minimum.Height);
                minWidth = Math.Max(minWidth, size.Minimum.Width);
            }

            if (rowCount > 1)
            {
                width = Math.Max(width, widthUsed);
                height = (height + Spacing) * rowCount - Spacing; // via MitchMilam 
            }

            return new SizeRequest(new Size(width, height), new Size(minWidth, minHeight));
        }

        protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
        {
            double rowHeight = 0;
            double yPos = y, xPos = x;

            foreach (var child in Children.Where(c => c.IsVisible))
            {
                var request = child.Measure(width, height);

                double childWidth = request.Request.Width;
                double childHeight = request.Request.Height;
                rowHeight = Math.Max(rowHeight, childHeight);

                if (xPos + childWidth > width)
                {
                    xPos = x;
                    yPos += rowHeight + Spacing;
                    rowHeight = 0;
                }

                var region = new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, childWidth, childHeight);
                LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion(child, region);
                xPos += region.Width + Spacing;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use UniformGrid with columns set to the number you need and rows = 1 in an ItemsPanelTemplate

Comment: @KevinCook The thing is, I'm not sure how many columns I need because different items will be of different lengths.

Comment: 1) Use a custom layout, Xamarin has an example that matches your needs, WrapLayout : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/custom/ (Note: I have no idea how many items you expect in this configuration, so performance/memory(!) might be an issue). 2) Otherwise CollectionViews...

Comment: @SushiHangover I'm not sure if I'm reading the guide right. Do I have to add a new class in my code behind in order to add a WrapLayout to my xaml?

Comment: Yes, you are creating a new subclass of  `Layout<View>` called `WrapLayout` in your project that you will then use in your XAML (or code)

Comment: @SushiHangover I feel really stupid, but I think there's something fundamental I'm missing here, that the guides don't really explain. If I just want to reorganize the view layout, why do I need to do anything in the code-behind? I thought the code-behind was just for business logic.

Comment: @JoeMorano Saying "code-behind" usually means the user code that is associate to a *single* XAML file, a XAML file is just a partial class with a matching partial class written in C#/F#. So technically a new subclass of Layout<View> is not called "code-behind", it is just code that is associated to your project, just like the C# `string` class is not "code-behind".

Comment: @JoeMorano  All the XAML elements you are using; `Label`, `StackLayout`, `Grid`, `Entry`, ... are written in C# code. Once **you** write a new `Layout` subclass, you can write XAML that includes it. Just like you could subclass `Label` and call it `MoranoLabel` and have it flash you favorite sports teams colors are someone types into it and then you could reference it in XAML and include it within a StackLayout..  You can also code everything in C#/F# and never use XAML... ;-)

Comment: Not sure what layout you actually are looking for? Full only horizontal so people need to scroll horizontal? Or wrapped? if wrapped take a look here : https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/CustomLayout/WrapLayout/

Comment: @Depechie Sorry I should have specified, I'm looking for a vertical scroll layout. So one stacklayout wrapped in a vertical scrolllayout, and everything else is non-scrollable and inside the stacklayout, if that makes sense. But yes wraplayout does appear to solve my problem, I'm currently trying to figure out how to apply it.

Comment: @JoeMorano Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769618/how-can-we-set-the-wrap-point-for-the-wrappanel/9770590#9770590 and the original Code Project article.  That probably won't work on Xamarin without modification but it may be a starting point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer to [My Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861673/how-can-i-make-buttons-wrap-around-like-in-a-tag-cloud-with-xamarin-forms/47989052#47989052). It is similar to your case.

Just need to custom `Layout` and manage its size and its children's arrangement.

#### Update:

> I'm getting a "Type local:WrapLayout not found in xmlns clr-namespace:Myapp" error.

Make Class `WrapLayout`  public , separate it from `ListPage`.

> I'm also a little confused about how to apply data binding here

We need to add a `BindableProperty` named `ItemSource` inside wraplayout ,and add subview when the property changed.

---

*Xmal*

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <local:WrapLayout x:Name="wrap" ItemSource="{Binding .}" Spacing="5" />
</ContentPage.Content>
```

---

*Code behind*

```
List<string> list = new List<string> {
            "11111111111111111111111",
            "22222",
            "333333333333333",
            "4",
            "55555555",
            "6666666666666666666666",
            "77777",
            "8888888888",
            "99999999999999999999999999999999"
};
this.BindingContext = list;
```

## Update: Button Event

We can define `event` inside `WrapLayout`, when we tap or long press on the button, trigger the events. And about the long press we should create custom renderers to implement it .

#### WrapLayout

```
namespace ImageWrapLayout
{
public class ButtonWithLongPressGesture : Button
{
    public EventHandler LongPressHandle;
    public EventHandler TapHandle;

    public void HandleLongPress(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Handle LongPressActivated Event
        LongPressHandle(sender, e);
    }

    public void HandleTap(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Handle Tap Event
        TapHandle(sender, e);
    }
}


public class WrapLayout : Layout<View>
{

    public List<string> ItemSource
    {
        get { return (List<string>)GetValue(ItemSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemSourceProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create
        (
            "ItemSource",
            typeof(List<string>),
            typeof(WrapLayout),
            propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) => ((WrapLayout)bindable).AddViews()
        );


    void AddViews()
    {
        Children.Clear();
        foreach (string s in ItemSource)
        {
            ButtonWithLongPressGesture button = new ButtonWithLongPressGesture();
            button.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
            button.Text = s;
            button.TextColor = Color.Black;
            Children.Add(button);

            button.TapHandle += WrapLayoutTapHandle;
            button.LongPressHandle = WrapLayoutLongPressHandle;
        }
    }


    public EventHandler WrapLayoutLongPressHandle;
    public EventHandler WrapLayoutTapHandle;




    public static readonly BindableProperty SpacingProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create
        (
            "Spacing",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(WrapLayout),
            10.0,
            propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) => ((WrapLayout)bindable).OnSizeChanged()
        );

    public double Spacing
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(SpacingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SpacingProperty, value); }
    }

    private void OnSizeChanged()
    {
        this.ForceLayout();
    }

    protected override SizeRequest OnMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
    {
        if (WidthRequest > 0)
            widthConstraint = Math.Min(widthConstraint, WidthRequest);
        if (HeightRequest > 0)
            heightConstraint = Math.Min(heightConstraint, HeightRequest);

        double internalWidth = double.IsPositiveInfinity(widthConstraint) ? double.PositiveInfinity : Math.Max(0, widthConstraint);
        double internalHeight = double.IsPositiveInfinity(heightConstraint) ? double.PositiveInfinity : Math.Max(0, heightConstraint);

        return DoHorizontalMeasure(internalWidth, internalHeight);
    }

    private SizeRequest DoHorizontalMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
    {
        int rowCount = 1;

        double width = 0;
        double height = 0;
        double minWidth = 0;
        double minHeight = 0;
        double widthUsed = 0;

        foreach (var item in Children)
        {
            var size = item.Measure(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);

            height = Math.Max(height, size.Request.Height);

            var newWidth = width + size.Request.Width + Spacing;
            if (newWidth > widthConstraint)
            {
                rowCount++;
                widthUsed = Math.Max(width, widthUsed);
                width = size.Request.Width;
            }
            else
                width = newWidth;

            minHeight = Math.Max(minHeight, size.Minimum.Height);
            minWidth = Math.Max(minWidth, size.Minimum.Width);
        }

        if (rowCount > 1)
        {
            width = Math.Max(width, widthUsed);
            height = (height + Spacing) * rowCount - Spacing; // via MitchMilam 
        }

        return new SizeRequest(new Size(width, height), new Size(minWidth, minHeight));
    }

    protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
    {
        double rowHeight = 0;
        double yPos = y, xPos = x;

        foreach (var child in Children.Where(c => c.IsVisible))
        {
            var request = child.Measure(width, height);

            double childWidth = request.Request.Width;
            double childHeight = request.Request.Height;
            rowHeight = Math.Max(rowHeight, childHeight);

            if (xPos + childWidth > width)
            {
                xPos = x;
                yPos += rowHeight + Spacing;
                rowHeight = 0;
            }

            var region = new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, childWidth, childHeight);
            LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion(child, region);
            xPos += region.Width + Spacing;
        }
    }
}
}
```

#### Custom Renderers for LongPress

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ButtonWithLongPressGesture), typeof(LongPressGestureRecognizerButtonRenderer))]
namespace ImageWrapLayout.iOS
{
class LongPressGestureRecognizerButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    ButtonWithLongPressGesture view;

    public LongPressGestureRecognizerButtonRenderer()
    {
        this.AddGestureRecognizer(new UILongPressGestureRecognizer((longPress) => {
            if (longPress.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began)
            {
                view.HandleLongPress(view, new EventArgs());
            }
        }));
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
            view = e.NewElement as ButtonWithLongPressGesture;

        //if(Control == null)
        //{
        UIButton but = Control as UIButton;
            but.TouchUpInside += (sender, e1) => {
                view.HandleTap(view, new EventArgs());
            };
        //}
    }
}
}
```

#### Usage (In Page.cs)

```
 inactiveList.WrapLayoutLongPressHandle += (sender, e) =>
 {
 };

 inactiveList.WrapLayoutTapHandle += (sender, e) =>
 {
 };
```

Comment: I tried your code, but I'm getting a "Type local:WrapLayout not found in xmlns clr-namespace:Myapp" error. I'm also a little confused about how to apply data binding here. Would I just put the `DataTemplate` inside the `WrapLayout` and then give the `WrapLayout` an `ItemsSource`?

Comment: @JoeMorano check my update again ,for the reason why you got the error.

Comment: I fixed that error, but now when I try to add data binding, I get this error: "Exception: System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array. occurred" I updated my code. Do you know what the error means?

Comment: @JoeMorano I see You set itemsource inside wraplayout .And also bind with data in xmal .You just need to set in xmal .refer to my example code

Comment: I think with your code the wraplayout doesn't get any data. I want to display an ObservableCollection of ListItems by calling `new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(App.ListItemRepo.GetInactiveListItems());`. Where should I call the `GetInactiveListItems` method?

Comment: @JoeMorano  in.the initial construct of the page

Comment: You mean inside `public partial class ListPage {...}`?

Comment: @JoeMorano yes，It is

Comment: So I should put something like `public partial class ListPage {inactiveList.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(App.ListItemRepo.GetInactiveListItems());}`?

Comment: You can put this inside the method ListPage(){} ,And set nothing on itemsource in xmal

Comment: When I do that, I get this error: "Unhandled Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. occurred". I'll update my code in my question.

Comment: @JoeMorano remove the itemsource set in xmal

Comment: Ah, there we go! Would you happen to know if it's possible to make the labels buttons instead, and call a method if they're tapped or long-pressed?

Comment: @JoeMorano tap for what？

Comment: In the previous ListView I had, if an item was tapped, it called a `PutBack` method, passing through the ListItem as parameters. If an item was long-pressed, a "delete" button appeared on the toolbar, and if that was pressed, it called a `Delete` method, passing through the ListItem as parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this: https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView

It's used just the same as ListView but has column support

[image]

Comment: Does this support uneven columns?

Comment: I tried implementing this, but the list isn't showing up at all.

Comment: @JoeMorano I have this issue, as well. It also doesn't help that `FlowListView` defines several properties with names similar to the native `ListView` _in addition to the properties already there_. Talk about confusing!

Answer (score 1):

You technically can do it. All VisualElements have a Rotation BindableProperty, so set rotation to 270.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty RotationProperty;
public static readonly BindableProperty RotationXProperty;
public static readonly BindableProperty RotationYProperty;
```

This code is from Visual Element Class. Also refer the sample below.

```
<ListView x:Name="MessagesListView" Rotation="270" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" RowHeight="40">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <ViewCell.View>
          <StackLayout>
            <!--mylayouthere-->
          </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell.View>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```